# yii2 unique validator only when field not empty

Tags: php, yii2

In Yii2 I have two fields in my Database: `email` and `shopId`

- `Email` and `shopId` should be `unique` together
- `Email` could also be `empty` (`NULL`) while `shopId` is always an integer

These are my rules in the Model:

```
[['email'],'default','value' => NULL],
[['shopId'], 'integer'],
[['email','shopId'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['email', 'shopId'], 'message' => 'Already taken!'],
```

This is not working when I have two entries with e.g. `email="NULL"` and `shopId="1"`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi. You may resolve this on the DB side by setting `email` and `shopId` as a joined unique key. The exact statement for that depends on your DBMS.

Comment: User `when` condition http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation

Comment: Thanks, the when condition worked. I cannot solve this on DBMS Side as the Model validation from Yii2 comes before

Answer (score 4):

I used the when condition inside the rule

```
[
    ['email', 'shopId'],
    'unique',
    'targetAttribute' => ['email', 'shopId'],
    'message' => 'Diese E-Mail Adresse ist bereits registriert!',
    'when' => function ($model) {
        return !empty($model->email);
    }
],
```

Answer (score 3):

While your solution is working it isn't technically correct. 
Validation rule

```
[['email','shopId'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['email', 'shopId']]
```

will validate `email` to be unique with given `shopId` if `email` is not empty (desired functionality), but it will also validate `shopId` to be unique with given `email` if `shopId` is not empty (unwanted). You are validating two fields with two queries to DB.

Validation rule that fits your needs is

```
[['email'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['email', 'shopId']]
```

saying "If `email` is not empty, check if combination of `email` and `shopId` is unique and bind result to `email` attribute".

Comment: And what if I have 10 attributes I want to be sure the combination is unique? How many rules do I have to define?

Comment: @user2511599 "not working" is not describing problem, so nobody can help you based on that. Question is what are you trying to achieve and what result you get instead. Attribute(s) at array index 0 are attributes on which rule would be applied, each one independently, and each one would get his own error message. Attributes at 'targetAttribute' is combination which should be unique.

In your case, attach validation rule to attribute which should get error message and which could be empty and list all 10 attributes at 'targetAttribute'. Problem is if more than one attribute can be empty.

Comment: @user2511599 if more than one attribute could be empty, you'll need to check it manually like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44409344/9034260

Answer (score 2):

Set `skipOnEmpty` property to `false` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$skipOnEmpty-detail

Comment: Thanks, but that's not working. i used a when condition

Comment: Worked fine for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution to enforce uniqueness across a set of fields, including nullable fields, which utilises the [yii\validators\UniqueValidator::$filter](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator#$filter-detail) callback in a generic PHP Trait that can be simply dropped into any Yii2 model. Full code examples below:

**Generic Trait** [common/models/traits/UniqueValidatorFilterTrait.php]

```
<?php

namespace common\models\traits;

use yii\db\ActiveQuery;

/**
 * Trait UniqueValidatorFilterTrait provides custom anonymous function callback methods.
 *
 * @package common\models\traits
 * @author Alec Pritchard <ajmedway@gmail.com>
 */
trait UniqueValidatorFilterTrait
{
    /**
     * Custom anonymous function for [[yii\validators\UniqueValidator::$filter]], used to modify the passed-in
     * [[\yii\db\ActiveRecord]] query to be applied to the DB query used to check the uniqueness of the input value.
     *
     * @param ActiveQuery $query
     * @param array $nullableUniqueFields the field names to ensure are considered and validated for the uniqueness
     * of a set of model attributes, even if some have empty/null values.
     * @see \yii\validators\UniqueValidator::$filter
     */
    public function filterFunctionUniqueWithNull(ActiveQuery $query, array $nullableUniqueFields = [])
    {
        // check if at least one of the $nullableUniqueFields currently has an empty value loaded
        $hasEmptyUniqueField = false;
        foreach ($nullableUniqueFields as $field) {
            if (empty($this->{$field})) {
                $hasEmptyUniqueField = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // proceed to modify AR query
        if ($hasEmptyUniqueField) {
            // change query item for the $nullableUniqueFields, which only checks against empty string by design
            // @link https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4333#issuecomment-57739619
            // ensure the composite unique constraint is applied to include NULL values for all $nullableUniqueFields
            foreach ($query->where as $whereItemKey => $whereItem) {
                if (!is_array($whereItem)) continue;
                foreach ($whereItem as $columnName => $value) {
                    // check if this column is one of the unique fields and if it currently has an empty string
                    if (str_replace($nullableUniqueFields, '', $columnName) != $columnName
                        && $value === '') {
                        // change from '' to NULL
                        $query->where[$whereItemKey][$columnName] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Model Usage**

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use common\models\traits\UniqueValidatorFilterTrait;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "my_table".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property null|string $email
 * @property int $shop_id
 */
class MyTable extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    use UniqueValidatorFilterTrait;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'my_table';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [
                ['email', 'shop_id'],
                'unique',
                'targetAttribute' => ['email', 'shop_id'],
                // ensure the composite unique constraint is applied to include NULL values for specified nullable fields
                'filter' => function (MyTableQuery $query) {
                    /* @see \common\models\traits\UniqueValidatorFilterTrait::filterFunctionUniqueWithNull() */
                    $this->filterFunctionUniqueWithNull($query, ['email', 'shop_id']);
                },
                // ensure that we don't skip on empty values, namely the `email` and/or `shop_id`
                'skipOnEmpty' => false,
            ],
        ];
    }
```

See the full discussion about this shortcoming of the Yii2 core unique validator, and reasons given by core dev team here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4333